# test 'where' clause using rspec

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

i have been learning to using rspec. 
i have to test this one:

```
Book.where(old:false, id:user.collections.select(:book_id).group(:book_id).map(&:book_id)).map{|b|[b.name, b.id] }
```

what i've already done is :

```
@user = Fabricate(:user)
@book1 = Fabricate(:book, old:false)
@book2 = Fabricate(:book, old:true)
@collection = Fabricate(:collection, book_id:@book1.id)
@collection2 = Fabricate(:collection, book_id:@book2.id)
@user.collections << @book1 << @book2
@books = Book.where(old:false, id:@user.collections.select(:book_id).group(:book_id).map(&:book_id)).map{|b|[b.name, b.id]}
```

.....

```
it "books" do
      subject[:filter].should == @books.map{|d| [d.name, d.id]}
end
```

it expected a book, but i got 0. did i forget something?
thanks in advance for any idea and help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very unreadable and hard to test. You should split the execution into smaller methods.

```
Book.where(old:false, id:user.collections.select(:book_id).group(:book_id).map(&:book_id)).map{|b|[b.name, b.id] }
```

could be

```
class Book
  def self.find_books_with_name(ids)
    where(old: false, id: ids).map { |b| [b.name, b.id] }
  end
end
```

Then you can call it with:

```
Book.find_books_and_name(user.collections.select(:book_id).group(:book_id).map(&:book_id))
```

which appears equally insane to me. Add to your user model and collection model something like

```
class Collection
  def self.book_ids
    select(:book_id).group(:book_id).map(&:book_id)
  end
end
```

Now you have

```
Book.find_books_and_name(user.collections.book_ids)
```

and now you can (and you should) test each method separately. A failure will be easier to spot and the test itself will be much more simple, without all that coupling to various models and records.

Comment: so sorry, i dont know how to explain the code easily. Anyway thank you so much for the answer! i will try to see and implement your answer